# Problem, site works on FF4 but not IE9 or other browsers

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I have been developing a website for a University coursework, and at the moment, i have managed to get the features i want.

The website works using jQuery,AJAX and PHP to allow the user to view articles and media that goes with each article. My problem is that the site works as it should on my laptop, on FF4 however it does not work on my IE9 or other browsers, I have given the link to a few people and they all encounter the same problem.

The problem is that when you click the story on the left (thats how you navigate) it fades the text as it should, but it is meant to load in the next story aswell.... If you guys could help, that would help alot.

Link to website: newspaper.nmyster.co.uk

Thanks

Comment: mind posting your code??

Comment: The first thing I would do is remove that blank line before the DOCTYPE. I'm not sure if IE still gets tripped up over that, but I know older versions of it do.

Comment: For Chrome, try using the console (hit ctrl+j) for debugging. When I check your site, there are a lot of errors and some console.log stuff (or atleast it looks like that). Try removing the logging stuff. (http://newspaper.nmyster.co.uk/scripts/javascript.js line 27)

Comment: works fine with Opera 11.10 and Chrome 12.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 is bugging out on this line:

```
console.log(storyId);
```

I'd suggest commenting this out.

If you enable debugging you should be able to see the same error.

Comment: Thanks so much! that worked, i think its because I have a console installed on firefox (firebug) so that line works, however not so on IE. Thanks again and for being so fast

Comment: tip 2: leaving debug messages in code has been a common mistake for years. You should remove your `console.log()` lines as soon as you've got the info you need from them, even if you expect to be putting them back again soon after. And you should also sweep your code for debug lines before deploying.

Answer (score 0):

These kind of problems always occurs by HTML and JavaScript support of broswer. First of all you shold validate your HTML by W3C validation. If the problem still persists than carefull check your javascript or jquery.

Comment: It was a line of code as pointed out by @trickwallet i had a line logging to the console, but on FF4 i have a console however i do not on IE9 and I doubt most the people i sent the links to will have either. Thanks